# wpf - looking for way to not freez ui while filling datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, asynchronous, datagrid

I want to prevent UI from freezing while I load data to an `ObservableCollection` (which is bind to `DataGrid`).

What I've already done is:

**ObservableCollection**:

```
private ObservableCollection<Product> _products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
public ObservableCollection<Product> Products
{
    get { return _products; }
    set
    {
        _products = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

**Method to get a products**:

```
void GetProducts()
{
    Products.Clear();

    var query = "Select * from Products";

    try
    {
        SqlCommand sqlCommand =
        new SqlCommand
        (
           query,
            Connection()
        );

        //creating async task
        var task = Task.Run(() =>
            DoAsyns2( sqlCommand ));
        await task;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {

    }
}
```

**My async method**:

```
internal void DoAsyns2( SqlCommand sqlCommand )
{
    SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
    Product prd;

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        prd = new Product()
        {
            Name = reader["Name"].ToString(),
            Amout = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Amout"]),
            Price = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Price"])
        };

        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            Products.Add(prd);
        });
    }
}
```

Generaly, everything works fine. Method is async until it comes to `Products.Add(prd)`. It totaly freezez UI until `while` loop ends.

I was digging in google for solution and found [this](https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/04/17/wpf-binding-to-an-asynchronous-collection/) page, about AsyncObservableCollection, but the solution is not working for me.

I also found something saying to add
`Thread.Sleep(millisecondsTimeout:1);` inside the `while` loop. It does make the UI not feeze, but it slows down the process of filling up the `DataGrid` dramatically (I'm dealing with > 50k rows)

Do somebody have another solution for my problem? 
Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you add an item to an ObservableCollection it will update the UI. You could make a List add the products there then overwrite the ObservableCollection.

```
internal void DoAsyns2( SqlCommand sqlCommand )
{
  SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
  Product prd;
  List productList = new List<Product>();

  while (reader.Read())
  {
    prd = new Product()
    {
        Name = reader["Name"].ToString(),
        Amout = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Amout"]),
        Price = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Price"])
    };
      productList.add(prd);
    }
  }
  Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
  {
    Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>(productList);
  };
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, I made a correct with calling `DoAsync`. I simplified code in question, and forgot about this place ;)

Comment: And what about that tw variable? :)

Comment: again sorry.. Could u take a look now?

Comment: Try to use a list then, that's what I suggested it should only update once, after you overwrite the Collection. (Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>(productList);)

Comment: Yes, I tried your method. You are creating local list and after it fills with values you asign it to Binded `Collection`. Its good way, but I would  to see progress of fetching data by 'live' filling datagrid. Is it even possible?

Comment: Then just simple try to swap your Dispatcher.Invoke to a Dispatcher.BeginInvoke or use a BackgroundWorker